# how to convert string list dictionary to list

Tags: python-3.x

```
filter = '[{"name":"MinPrice","value": "50"},{"name":"MaxPrice","value": "100"}]'
```

how can I convert this string to list? Not changing actual data.Data should not change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: @Rakesh yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> f = '[{"name":"MinPrice","value": "50"},{"name":"MaxPrice","value": "100"}]'

>>> output = ast.literal_eval(f)
>>> type(output)
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please don't call it `filter`,
as that shadows a very nice [builtin identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).
I will rename as `filt`.

Use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> filt = '[{"name":"MinPrice","value": "50"},{"name":"MaxPrice","value": "100"}]'
>>> lst = json.loads(filt)
>>> len(lst)
2
>>> lst[0]
{'name': 'MinPrice', 'value': '50'}
>>> 
>>> lst[1]
{'name': 'MaxPrice', 'value': '100'}
```